# AspNetCore.Mvc ApiController stoppes with Segmentation fault when hosted on rasbian

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have developed a .net core asp rest api in visual studio on windows 10. Everything is working until I tried to host the application on a raspberry pi with rasbian. The application hosts a html file and three javascript files. There are no problem with the html file, but when the application tries to send the javascript files it prints "Segmentation fault" and stops.

[Screenshot Running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFPJY.jpg)

Develop environment:
- Windows 10
- Visual studio 15.8.1 Community
- .NET core 2.0

Hosting environment:
-Raspberry pi B+
-Rasbian 9
- .NET core 2.0

So far I have tried to transfer the files with winSCP vs Google drive, but its the same. I have also tried to remove all line breaks cr and lf, and set the file permissions to read/write.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any external nuget packages (apart from Microsoft.* ones).

Comment: Yes, i'm using CsvHelper 7.1.1. Can this cause problems?

Comment: I tried to uninstall the nuget package, so that i only have packages from Mircosoft, but i still get the same error.